# Save Miliseconds precision with DateTime in MySQL using C# and Fluenthibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, fluent-nhibernate

I have been trying to save a c# DateTime to MySQL datetime(6) without much success. I need to store the datetime with milliseconds precision.
Here is how I setup my a test table.

```
create table test_date_time
( 
    ID int not null auto_increment
    , Created_By datetime(6)
    , primary key (ID) 
);
```

In C# I specify an entity type and the field mappings as follows:

```
public class test_date_time
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? Created_By { get; set; }
}

public class test_date_time_Map : ClassMap<test_date_time>
{
    public test_date_time_Map()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Created_By);
    }

}
```

And here is how I connect to the database and store a DateTime:

```
string Connection_String = string.Format(@"Server={0};Database={1};Uid={2};Pwd={3};SSL Mode=Required;CertificateFile={4};"
    , Server, Database, User, Password, Certificate_File);

ISessionFactory Session_Factory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(Connection_String))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<test_date_time_Map>())
    .BuildSessionFactory();

var Session = Session_Factory.OpenSession();

var t = new test_date_time() { Created_By = DateTime.UtcNow };
Session.SaveOrUpdate(t);

Session.CreateCriteria<test_date_time>().List<test_date_time>();

var Status = Session.CreateCriteria<test_date_time>().List<test_date_time>();

Session.Close();
```

By reading various posts I also tried to change the mapping to a custom type via:

```
public class test_date_time_Map : ClassMap<test_date_time>
{
    public test_date_time_Map()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Created_By).CustomType("datetime(6)");
    }

}
```

but that only leads to an exception saying "Could not determine type for: datetime(6), for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Created_By)"

Anyone knows how to get subsecond precision saved?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new usertype (implement IUserType) with the NullSafeSet implementation doing the ToString() with the precision that you want. (eg. DateTimeWithMilliseconds)

You can then either write a custom convention to apply that to all DateTimes (if you're using automapping), or do:

```
Map(x => x.Created_By).CustomType<DateTimeWithMilliseconds>()
```

in your mapping.